# Substring from a certain length of characters

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a series of Strings from a log.

Currently the strings look similar to

```
:someuser some dates/times whatever :This is the message
```

I was thinking of using a Scanner to check that the starting character is indeed a ":", and if it is find the length of characters to the next ":" and then use substring(length) to get rid of the first part of the string before the actual message.

However I just can't think of how to do this properly (mainly finding the length between the two ":"). How would I go about this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [String#indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

Comment: String#split() would do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming you want to throw out everything before the last ':'?
Assuming you've already read the line into String line:

```
String message = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(":")+1);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find the length of the text between the two `:`s:

```
String mystr=:someuser some dates/times whatever :This is the message;
int len=(mystr.split(":")[1]).length();
```

Where `.split` splits your `mystr` and returns an array of strings. There `0th` element is anything before the `1st` appearance of `:` and the `1st` element of the array is the text you want to know the length of.

Finally, `.lenght()` will return the length of that text.